# Oracle regex separate diskgroup name and the rest

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a column whose value is

col1
+ASM_DISK_GROUP_TIER1/mydb/data/myfile.111.326

```
i would like to split the string into something like this

ASM_DISK_GROUP_TIER1        /mydb/data/myfile.111.326         myfile.111.326   
(without the +sign)

however 
select regexp_substr(col1,'[^/]*') from dual
gives me +ASM_DISK_GROUP_TIER1
```

and i am clueless how to get the second and the third part i.e
/mydb/data/myfile.111.326         myfile.111.326

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle regular expression support is quite limited -- unlike other languages which let you use parentheses to get back parts of the match, in Oracle you can only get the whole matched string (or its start or end position with `REGEXP_INSTR`).
There are various ways to work around this if you have to, using regexp magic and arithmetic, but in this case you should admit that you are actually just looking for the first and last occurrence of `/` and code accordingly:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col1, 2, INSTR(col1, "/") - 2) "Disk Group",
       SUBSTR(col1, INSTR(col1, "/")) "Path",
       SUBSTR(col1, INSTR(col1, "/", -1)) "File Name"
FROM ...
```

(Not tested).

Comment: Actually you might want `SUBSTR(col1, INSTR(col1, "/", -1) + 1)` for the file name so that the `/` before it isn't included.